# Tool for quick java code coverage check for Live deployment based on UI interaction

Tags: java, code-analysis, code-coverage

My context is I have an application (consider it as a black box for now) deployed on a JBoss server. I am in the process of analyzing and studying the application and has a very limited time frame to study it.

In addition, I am able to run the application on an IDE (IntelliJ) on Debug mode. (Just FYI)

I am looking for a short cut to code coverage for above mentioned Java application deployed on a JBoss app server. Below is my specific requirement about the code analysis/coverage tool:

1. It can be a standalone Tool or IDE plugin or co-deployable on JBoss server.
2. Coverage should be based on the live User interaction with the deployed application and may or may not based on any automation, because I don't have working automation currently.
3. It should easily readable report live coverage and not a static code analysis.
4. I should be able to drill down into reports to see specific class and methods covered (having % coverage would be an additional bonus, but not necessarily my requirement)
5. Prefer a open source tool/plugin.

   Is there any tools/plugins which closely matches my requirement? Something like a heat map for Java code.

Also, I am not sure if code coverage OR Profiler that would match my requirement.

Thanks in advance for the help.